# Javascript code doesn't fire when called from functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I try to call a JS file from `functions.php` file in Wordpress. When I run the same code in jsFiddle, everything works. So, my conclusion is that it is Wordpress specific.

You can find the jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/59w45k06/13/)

And this is my code in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_assets' );

function my_enqueue_assets() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'cookies-consent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/cookies-consent/cookies-consent.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('cookies-consent', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/cookies-consent/cookies-consent.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('cookies-consent-content', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/cookies-consent/content.js');

}
```

All three URLs are valid and accessible from the website. All are there in the source code and when I visit them, they open without any error.

When I run the same code in jsFiddle with the `content.js` file in the Javascript panel, I can see the popup box on the bottom right.

Also, I don't have any error on the console. And if I add a `console.log('hello');` in the `content.js` it is still not in the console output.

EDIT: The problem was fixed. It was a Breeze plugin issue that moved all the JS files to the `head` tag. So, I had to exclude it to keep loading it to the footer.

Comment: Can you provide a link, or are you working locally? Is the css being applied?

Comment: Usually don’t post links since it might be offline after months. But this is the one www.stackprime.com

Comment: When I inspect the source of www.stackprime.com and search for string **cookies-consent** I see no files enqueued which have to do with **cookies-consent**.  Also I see a javascript error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null in file breeze_c189e3fe9cf5476c30ec3ab2c90d26eb.js on line 9.

Comment: I see that you are using the Breeze – WordPress Cache Plugin, and also managed to find the minified js file for **cookies-content** script.  Did you try to wrap your script in a `jQery(document).ready(function(){})` ?

Comment: @OmarTanti Check my updated post. I managed to fix it thanks for pointing me to the Breeze plugin. It automatically moved the JS to the header instead of the footer and the code couldn't work. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, glad that you managed to resolve the issue :) You can try to keep using the Breeze plugin without excluding the file by passing the 'footer' parameter to the wp_enqueue_script:

wp_enqueue_script('cookies-consent-content', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/cookies-consent/content.js', ['cookies-content'], '0.1', true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes scripts can depened on other scripts so you need to make sure that the scripts are enqueued in the right sequence.  The wp_enqueue_script function accepts `$in_footer` parameter to make sure that the script loads in the footer if it depends on other scripts which are being loaded in the header.  It also accepts another parameter`$deps` (dependencies).

Even though you are using the Breeze – WordPress Cache Plugin you can still stry to set the `$in_footer` parameter to true in order to avoid excluding the script from the caching plugin. Try to change your wp_enqueue_scripts as follows:

```
wp_enqueue_script('cookies-consent', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/cookies-consent/cookies-consent.js', array(), '0.1', true);

wp_enqueue_script('cookies-consent-content', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/cookies-consent/content.js', array('cookies-content'), '0.1', true);
```